# fetch json on service instead on controller

Tags: angularjs, json

is it posible to fetch the data json on services, currently im using on my productdetail controller. and second, when i open my product list page it request the json. and when i go to the detail product page is request the json again. i thought it only need to request one time only. if thats, why i must request the same json multiple times. is there a way to request json for one times?

services.js

```
.factory('Product', ['$http', function($http){
        return{
            get: function(callback){
                return $http.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vicariosinaga/learn/master/products.json').then(function(response){
                    return response.data;
                });
            }
        };
    }])
```

productctrl

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('productCtrl',['$scope', 'Product', function($scope,Product) {
        $scope.title="List Product";
        Product.get().then(function(data) {
            $scope.products = data;
        });
    }]);
```

productdetailctrl

```
.controller('productDetailsCtrl',['$scope','$stateParams', 'Product', function($scope,$stateParams,Product){
        $scope.id=$stateParams.id;
        Product.get().then(function(data) {
            $scope.singleItem = data.filter(function(entry){
                return entry.id === $scope.id;
            })[0];
            // console.log($scope.singleItem);
            // console.log($stateParams);
        });     
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Cache the json after fetching. If cached, return from cache else fetch.

```
.factory('Product', ['$http', function($http,$q){
    var service = {};
    service.get: function(callback){
         if(service.productJSON){
            return $q(function(resolve,reject){
              resolve(service.productJSON);
          })
        }
        else{
            return $http.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vicariosinaga/learn/master/products.json').then(function(response){
                service.productJSON = 
                return response.data;
            });
        }
      }
    return service;

}])
```